# Error Installing lxc 1.0.0

Tags: installation, lxc, dependencies

I am trying to install lxc 1.0.0 but I get this error when I run this command

I have added the following repos to my sources.lst file

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-lxc/daily/ubuntu saucy main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-lxc/daily/ubuntu saucy main
```

and ran apt-get install command. BTW my Ubuntu is 13.04 server image. Can someone help me resolve this error?

```
root@host:/work/user1# apt-get install lxc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cgmanager-tests : Depends: cgmanager but it is not going to be installed
 lxc : Depends: cgmanager but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: liblxc1 (= 1.0.1+master~20140324-2000-0ubuntu1~ppa1~saucy1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu15 is to be installed or
                file-rc (>= 0.8.16) but it is not installable
       Recommends: uidmap but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to install lxc-1.0.0-alpha1 one 13.04 (raring ringtail). I just have to enable raring-backports in my /etc/apt/sources.list and it worked.

The following commands will install lxc-1.0.0-alpha1

```
apt-get install liblxc0/raring-backports
apt-get install python3-lxc/raring-backports
apt-get install lxc/raring-backports
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running `raring` but you specified a `saucy` PPA. This isn't guaranteed to work. And in your case it clearly isn't. Change it to `raring`. Or better yet, upgrade to 13.10; you're past the [support window](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) for 13.04.

Comment: @michael-hampton..lxc 1.0.0 is not officially available on raring repo and I don't think we can officially upgrade to 13.10. Need to make this work on 13.04 :)

Comment: 13.04 is already dead, so it looks like you're going to be upgrading.